# Which actions in Kingdoms of Amalur grant experience?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Title says it all - just wondering if you gain experience for things like crafting or persuasion attempts, or if it's just for completing quests and killing things.

Comment: I haven't noticed if persuasion or crafting grants XP, so I'm not posting this as an answer. I *do* know successfully dispelling wards, and picking locks both grant XP.

Comment: I believe @spugsley found that crafting grants XP - it may very well be that all skills grant XP, but of course that will require further testing.

Comment: This question needs more love.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Things that get you experience:**

- Successfully picking locks (only if you do it manually, if you force open the lock you won't get experience)
- Doing quests
- Killing enemies and civilians
- Dispelling wards on chests
- Activating lorestones
- Finding new locations

**Things that won't get you experience:**

- Crafting, Sagecrafting and doing Alchemy
- Stealing items, regardless of whether you do it successfully or get caught
- Killing chickens =(
- Disarming traps
- Successful persuasion attempts

Comment: Trap disarming also does not grant any experience :(

Comment: @agent86 Added!

Comment: I think discovering a new location grants experience, can anyone confirm?

Comment: What about successful persuasion attempts?

Comment: @jwaddell Discovering new locations *does* in fact grant XP.

Comment: @jwaddell Well i did like 3-4 successful persuasion attempts already and i haven't noticed any exp boost to it,so even if it is there it is so low it's not worth mentioning.Also there wont be many times when you can use the persuasion and it will only give you one or two extra items (but nothing special) when you do,basically if you ask me investing in persuasion is not really worth it in this game,at least not for your first playthrough.

Comment: No bonus for persuasion attempts as far as EXP is concerned.  Also, killing game (deer, bulls, crabs, etc...) do not offer extra exp.  Some persuasion attempts that are difficult to unluck will start a quest in turn causing exp gain.  So having persuasion and listening to everything an NPC says that is a "white" selection will ultimately bring about a potential quest if you successfully complete the persuasion.